# How to read float values from a file and initialize array?

Tags: java

i am trying to read float values from a .txt file to initialize an array but it is throwing a InputMismatchException

Here's the method and the sample values i am trying to read from the file are  4 2 1 4

```
    public class Numbers {
    private Float [] numbers;
    public int default_size = 10;
    String fileName = new String();

    public void initValuesFromFile()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        fileName = scan.next();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader  = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(fileName));
            String input = null;

            while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    numbers[i] = Float.parseFloat(input);
        }
        }
    }
        catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you have `numbers` defined?

Comment: 4 2 1 4 numbers must be at different line in a.txt.

Comment: If `4 2 1 4` are defined on one line then its not going to work

Comment: it's at the top of the class. i will update the code with the whole class

Comment: If all those numbers are in one line, then you need to split them by space and then run a for loop in the array returned by the split method.

Comment: i tried to split them by space but the numbers array is defined as float so when i try to do that it gives me an error that i cannot convert it to string. is there any other possible solution without changing the .txt file?

Comment: you can use split method.

Comment: i tried that already. I explained what the issue is when i try to use it in the above comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read line from the file and split using space or even better `\\s+` and then run a for loop for all items split into an array of strings and parse each number and store them in a `List<Float>` and this way will work even if you have multiple numbers in further different lines. Here is the code you need to try,

```
Float[] numbers = new Float[4];
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = scan.next();
scan.close();
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String input = null;

    while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String nums[] = input.trim().split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Float.parseFloat(nums[i]);
        }
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
} catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This prints,

```
[4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: This did work but is it possible to do it without the use of Arraylist?

Comment: @JustinMacwan: Yes you can but then it will be limited. You will have to know how many numbers are present in line plus numbers will have to be in just one line. If numbers are more than the declared array size, it may run into ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. Let me limit my solution to not use ArrayList.

Comment: @JustinMacwan: Updated code to not use `ArrayList`. Check now.

Comment: The code works perfect but i do have files with more values for input so yeah it gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. I guess i will just use the solution with ArrayList then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JustinMacwan: Yes, for varying number of numbers in file, you won't be able to fixate the array length, which is where you will have to go for `ArrayList`.